# C++ syntax: void CLASS functionName()?

Tags: c++, syntax

I came across some standalone code without headers. I believe it to be straight C/C++, but am not sure. If so, what does the "CLASS" in the following mean? I know it's not a class declaration or definition. Is this a method of a class named "CLASS"?

```
void CLASS functionName(){
  //
  //
  //
}
```

I'm used to seeing `<returnType> <functionName>() {...}`, but not the above. Am I forgetting something? (Pardon me, as I've been in JS and Objective-C lately.)

Comment: There is presumably a `#define CLASS` hidden somewhere.

Comment: `CLASS` might be a macro? Can you find definition for `CLASS` somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it's not common AFAIK, it could be that CLASS is a macro as below. Since its name is `CLASS`, I would say it's more likely that it's a macro for a class or namespace.

**1. Class Name**

```
class A
{
   void functionName();
};

#define CLASS A::

void CLASS functionName()
{}
```

**2. Namespace**

```
namespace A
{
   void functionName();
};

#define CLASS A::

void CLASS functionName()
{}
```

**3. Calling Convertion**

```
// or __cdecl, etc.
define CLASS __stdcall
```

**4. Others**

There could be others (e.g., a macro for a pointer) which are syntactically correct, but they're less likely in your case. Or it could simply be a comment, as Hostile points out below.

Comment: Or a modifier for the [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) like _cdecl or __fastcall (depending on the compiler).

Comment: Hmmm... that first idea makes sense if they were trying to get C/C++ interoperability in some very strange way.  I hadn't thought of that!

Comment: Sure, though usually I go by @HostileFork or abbreviate as @Fork.  :)  Worth noting perhaps is that that the use of a macro like `CLASS` instead of `/* CLASS */` is that it helps apply compile time to catch variants in spelling like `/* CLASSS */` which reduces confusion to those reading the code as well as (more importantly) any automated tool that's checking a property.  An example I came across a while ago was the application of INTUSE (for "internal use") in the standard library implementing functions like `printf`: http://hostilefork.com/2010/03/14/where-the-printf-rubber-meets-the-road/

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely not standard C or C++, as there's only a few things that could legally go in-between the `void` and the function name (a star, for example, to make the return type `void *`).  This is probably a macro that's being used by some compiler extension or external tool.  Without more information about where you found this code I don't think I can offer more than that; where did you find this?

Comment: That was my guess, too. It's from http://www.rawness.es/cielab/?lang=en. They're using preprocessor directives elsewhere, so it's possible another is being used that's not shown here.

Comment: While I hate to presume to argue what answer is *actually* correct in this particular case, if you look at that Rawness link you posted it says "based in Jac­ques Des­mis work" who is listed as a contributor to Rawtherapee, which suggests that pure documentation is the purpose (along with my answer pointing out exactly what it is that it documents).  Could be wrong, just noting accreditation to Jacques Desmis on rawtherapee is here:    http://code.google.com/p/rawtherapee/source/browse/AUTHORS.txt?name=branch_3.0

Comment: +1 for asking for context. @HostileFork: "dcraw.cc" is the name of one of the files returned by the Google Code Search and "dcraw" is directly mentioned on the rawness page referenced. Good call.

Answer (score 1):

I used Google's Code Search (which can come in handy sometimes) and found an instance of this in ["rawtherapee"](http://rawtherapee.com/blog/features):

http://codesearch.google.com/#search/&q=%22void%20CLASS%22&type=cs&exact_package=http://rawtherapee.googlecode.com/hg/

Not surprisingly, the definition is a macro (there's little else it could be), but it's just an empty `#define`.  The definition is explained [here](http://codesearch.google.com/#search/&q=%22CLASS%22&type=cs&exact_package=http://rawtherapee.googlecode.com/hg/):

> All global variables are defined here, and all functions that
>     access them are prefixed with "CLASS".  Note that a thread-safe
>     C++ class cannot have non-const static local variables.

At least in that project, it's basically being used for documentation purposes, and purposefully is stripped out by the preprocessor.  I've seen this done marking pointer parameters as `IN` or `OUT` before, sort of like in [MIDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Interface_Definition_Language).

@EricZ has made a good inventory of *possible* uses.  Yet I am fairly sure this is what you're seeing, because of the authorship and project name overlap between Rawness (your case) and Rawtherapee...

Comment: ++1 Thanks! This answer is specific to the original project I was looking at! But for the general case, I granted the answer to @Eric Z.

Comment: Understood, my philosophy as well, it's probably more useful to the majority of future visitors...