# What use cases necessitate #define without a token-string?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I have encountered the `#define` pre-processor directive before while learning C, and then also encountered it in some code I read. But apart from using it to definite substitutions for constants and to define macros, I've not really understook the special case where it is used without a "body" or token-string.

Take for example this line:

```
#define OCSTR(X)
```

Just like that! What could be the use of this or better, when is this use of `#define` necessary?

Comment: This can be useful in conjunction with another set of directives that allow conditional compilation. A #define without a token-string removes occurrences of identifier from the source file. The identifier remains defined and can be tested by using the #if defined and #ifdef directives.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is used in two cases.  The first and most frequent involves
conditional compilation:

```
#ifndef XYZ
#define XYZ
//  ...
#endif
```

You've surely used this yourself for include guards, but it can also be
used for things like system dependencies:

```
#ifdef WIN32
//  Windows specific code here...
#endif
```

(In this case, WIN32 is more likely defined on the command line, but it
could also be defined in a `"config.hpp"` file.) This would normally
only involve object-like macros (without an argument list or
parentheses).

The second would be a result of conditional compilation.  Something
like:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define TEST(X) text(X)
#else
#define TEST(X)
#endif
```

That allows writing things like:

```
TEST(X);
```

which will call the function if `DEBUG` is defined, and do nothing if it
isn't.

Comment: Accepted this not because others ain't correct, but because it adds more clarification to the correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Such macro usually appears in pair and inside conditional `#ifdef` as:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
   #define OCSTR(X)
#else
   #define OCSTR(X)  SOME_TOKENS_HERE
#endif
```

Another example,

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
   #define NAMESPACE_BEGIN(X) namespace X {
   #define NAMESPACE_END }
#else
   #define NAMESPACE_BEGIN(X) 
   #define NAMESPACE_END
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

One odd case that I recently dug up to answer a question turned out to be simply commentary in nature.  The code in question looked like:

```
void CLASS functionName(){
  //
  //
  //
}
```

I discovered it was just an empty `#define`, which the author had chosen to document that the function accessed global variables in the project:

[C++ syntax: void CLASS functionName()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088292/c-syntax-void-class-functionname/7088428#7088428)

So not really that different from if it said `/* CLASS */`, except not allowing typos like `/* CLAAS */`...some other small benefits perhaps (?)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with every answer, but I'd like to point out a small trivial thing.

Being a C purist I've grown up with the assertion that EACH AND EVERY `#define` should be an expression, so, even if it's common practice using:

```
#define WHATEVER
```

and test it with

```
#ifdef WHATEVER
```

I think it's always better writing:

```
#define WHATEVER (1)
```

also `#debug` macros shall be expressions:

```
#define DEBUG (xxx) (whatever you want for debugging, value)
```

In this way, you are completely safe from misuse of `#macros` and prevents nasty problems (especially in a 10 million line C project)

Comment: This `#if` vs `#ifdef` debate may interest you, I fall personally on the side of `#if` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135069/ifdef-vs-if-which-is-better-safer

Comment: Comes to mind the effective use of #if 0 for commenting out entire pieces of code :D. Btw the debate it's interesting. As usual there's not a right or wrong way to do things, it's up to what you're doing. I will give it a read ASAP. Thanks.

Comment: In my case, when i have `#define TEST` without an expression, `#elif TEST` macro throws an error saying `error: expected value in expression` in clang.

Answer (score 0):

This can be used when you may want to silent some function. For example in debug mode you want to print some debug statements and in production code you want to omit them:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define PRINT(X) printf("%s", X)
#else
#define PRINT(X)  // <----- silently removed
#endif
```

Usage:

```
void foo ()
{
  PRINT("foo() starts\n");
  ...
}
```

Comment: Your answer (and many others') is true but your example is dangerous. What if there is a if() with no enclosing { } is present before the PRINT(X) ? To readers : beware, this is only a simple example not to be used as is.

Comment: That's the reason why in C/C++ each macro shall be an expression just to avoid that sort of scenarios. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

`#define` macros are simply replaced, literally, by their replacement text during preprocessing. If there is no replacement text, then ... they're replaced by nothing! So this source code:

```
#define FOO(x)

print(FOO(hello world));
```

will be preprocessed into just this:

```
print();
```

This can be useful to get rid of things you don't want, like, say, `assert()`. It's mainly useful in conditional situations, where under some conditions there's a non-empty body, though.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the above responses, it can be useful when debugging your code.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define debug(msg) fputs(__FILE__ ":" (__LINE__) " - " msg, stderr)
#else
#define debug(msg)
#endif
```

So, when you are debugging, the function will print the line number and file name so you know if there is an error. And if you are not debugging, it will just produce no output

Answer (score 0):

There are many uses for such a thing.

For example, one is for the macro to have different behavior in different builds. For example, if you want debug messages, you could have something like this:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
  #define DEBUG_LOG(X, ...) however_you_want_to_print_it
#else
  #define DEBUG_LOG(X, ...) // nothing
#endif
```

Another use could be to customize your header file based on your system. This is from my mesa-implemented OpenGL header in linux:

```
#if !defined(OPENSTEP) && (defined(__WIN32__) && !defined(__CYGWIN__))
#  if defined(__MINGW32__) && defined(GL_NO_STDCALL) || defined(UNDER_CE)  /* The generated DLLs by MingW with STDCALL are not compatible with the ones done by Microsoft's compilers */
#    define GLAPIENTRY 
#  else
#    define GLAPIENTRY __stdcall
#  endif
#elif defined(__CYGWIN__) && defined(USE_OPENGL32) /* use native windows opengl32 */
#  define GLAPIENTRY __stdcall
#elif defined(__GNUC__) && (__GNUC__ * 100 + __GNUC_MINOR__) >= 303
#  define GLAPIENTRY
#endif /* WIN32 && !CYGWIN */

#ifndef GLAPIENTRY
#define GLAPIENTRY
#endif
```

And used in header declarations like:

```
GLAPI void GLAPIENTRY glClearIndex( GLfloat c );

GLAPI void GLAPIENTRY glClearColor( GLclampf red, GLclampf green, GLclampf blue, GLclampf alpha );

GLAPI void GLAPIENTRY glClear( GLbitfield mask );

...
```

(I removed the part for `GLAPI`)

So you get the picture, a macro that is used in some cases and not used in other cases could be defined to something on those cases and nothing to those other cases.

Other cases could be as follows:

If the macro doesn't take parameters, it could be just to declare some case. A famous example is to guard header files. Another example would be something like this

```
#define USING_SOME_LIB
```

and later could be used like this:

```
#ifdef USING_SOME_LIB
...
#else
...
#endif
```

Could be that the macro was used at some stage to do something (for example log), but then on release the owner decided the log is not useful anymore and simply removed the contents of the macro so it becomes empty. This is not recommended though, use the method I mentioned in the very beginning of the answer.

Finally, it could be there just for more explanation, for example you can say

```
#define DONT_CALL_IF_LIB_NOT_INITIALIZED
```

and you write functions like:

```
void init(void);
void do_something(int x) DONT_CALL_IF_LIB_NOT_INITIALIZED;
```

Although this last case is a bit absurd, but it would make sense in such a case:

```
#define IN
#define OUT

void function(IN char *a, OUT char *b);
```