# #define IDENTIFIER without a token

Tags: c

What does the following statement mean:

```
#define FAHAD
```

I am familiar with the statements like:

```
#define FAHAD 1
```

But what does the #define statement without a token signify?
Is it that it is similar to a constant definition?

Comment: Also see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594808/what-use-cases-necessitate-define-without-a-token-string) for answers.

Answer (score 28):

Defining a constant without a value acts as a flag to the preprocessor, and can be used like so:

```
#define MY_FLAG
#ifdef MY_FLAG
/* If we defined MY_FLAG, we want this to be compiled */
#else
/* We did not define MY_FLAG, we want this to be compiled instead */
#endif
```

Answer (score 10):

it means that `FAHAD` is defined, you can later check if it's defined or not with:

```
#ifdef FAHAD
  //do something
#else
  //something else
#endif
```

Or:

```
#ifndef FAHAD //if not defined
//do something
#endif
```

A real life example use is to check if a function or a header is available for your platform, usually a build system will define macros to indicate that some functions or headers exist before actually compiling, for example this checks if `signal.h` is available:

```
#ifdef HAVE_SIGNAL_H
#   include <signal.h>
#endif/*HAVE_SIGNAL_H*/
```

This checks if some function is available

```
#ifdef HAVE_SOME_FUNCTION
//use this function
#else
//else use another one
#endif
```

Answer (score 9):

Any `#define` results in replacing the original identifier with the replacement tokens.  If there are no replacement tokens, the replacement is empty:

```
#define DEF_A "some stuff"
#define DEF_B 42
#define DEF_C
printf("%s is %d\n", DEF_A, DEF_B DEF_C);
```

expands to:

```
printf("%s is %d\n", "some stuff", 42 );
```

I put a space between `42` and `)` to indicate the "nothing" that `DEF_C` expanded-to, but in terms of the language at least, the output of the preprocessor is merely a stream of tokens.  (Actual compilers generally let you see the preprocessor output.  Whether there will be any white-space here depends on the actual preprocessor.  For GNU cpp, there is one.)

As in the other answers so far, you can use `#ifdef` to test whether an identifier has been `#define`d.  You can also write:

```
#if defined(DEF_C)
```

for instance.  These tests are positive (i.e., the identifier *is* defined) even if the expansion is empty.

Answer (score 2):

```
#define FAHAD
```

this will act like a compiler flag, under which some code can be done.
this will instruct the compiler to compile the code present under this compiler option

```
#ifdef FAHAD
printf();
#else
/* NA */
#endif
```